# Window setTimeout is not assigned due to updatepanel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an issue due to UpdatePanel. I am assigning windows timeout from code behind(snippet is on page load). The time is assigned correctly for the first time. But when I change dropdownlist or some other controls which cause page load, the time is not assigned. But I want the session time to be reset whenever pageload occurs.

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 alert(<%=mintTimeout%>);
 window.setTimeout("endSession();",<%=mintTimeout%>);
 function endSession()
 {
     alert("Your session has expired. You will be redirected to the login page.");
 }
```

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true">
            <asp:ListItem>a</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>b</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>c</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
```

and my code behind is

```
 public int mintTimeout = 0;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Timeout = 1;
        mintTimeout = (Session.Timeout) * 60000;
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Please help me to get through this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear and reassign timeout on each postback. You can use `pageLoad` function for this. Change your script as below:

```
var sessionExpiredTimeout = null;

function pageLoad() {
    if(sessionExpiredTimeout){
        clearTimeout(sessionExpiredTimeout);
    }
    sessionExpiredTimeout = setTimeout(endSession, <%= mintTimeout %> );
}

function endSession() {
    alert("Your session has expired. You will be redirected to the login page.");
}
```